# Facebook Page Access Token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to bind the rating information from Facebook Page into my website.

First i get the Information from the Graph API Explorer, and that works well.

Know i have tried to programming this with javascript and i have problems with the page access token.

```
      FB.api('/{page-id}/ratings', function(response) {
          console.log(response);

      });
```

The Stacktrace:

[image]

How can i include/programming the Page Access Token into the function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Page Token, and you need to use it on your server - do not use the JavaScript SDK for this. Using a Page Token on the client would be a bad idea, you should never expose a Token on the client - especially not an **Extended Page Token**, which is what you would want to use in that case).

How to generate an Extended Page token is explained in the docs, here are some links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Here´s a general tutorial:

- Get a User Token with the `manage_pages` permission
- Extend the User Token
- Get an Extended Page Token with `/page-id?fields=access_token`

You should also consider caching the results in your database instead of reading from the Facebook API whenever a new user hits your page.

Comment: What about using the FB PHP SDK? Would that obfuscate the token so that it could be protected? I'm finding it hard to locate information/docs on authenticating FB server side. The SDK appears straightforward and well documented.

Comment: why obfuscate? it´s server side anyway. i would authorize with the js sdk though, and send the token to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To access page specific data, first you need to obtain a page access token for the specific page and then call the api along with that token.

```
//Load FB js SDK here

function getpages() {
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {
        console.log('page details');
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response.data,function(index, item){
            $("#fbpgs").append("<div class='row'>"+item.name+"<button onclick='getads("+item.id+",\""+item.access_token+"\")' >Show details</button></div>");
        });
    });
}

function get_page_data(pid,token) {
    $("#lead_forms").html("");
    $(".dv").removeClass("seldiv");
    $(dv).parent().parent().addClass("seldiv");
    FB.api("/"+pid+"/leadgen_forms",{access_token : token}, function(response) {
        console.log('page details');
        console.log(response);
    });
}

<button onclick='getpages()'>load pages</a>
<div class='fbpgs'></div>
```